# Lock PC and show the screen

Tags: windows, screen, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I have a PC running windows 7 with 2 screens connected, and I want to put the PC in lock mode so nobody can access and modify anything from it. 
But when it is in lock mode only the login screen appears and I want to see at least on one screen what the PC is processing(basically I have a putty opened session with a running script that shows some stats about a system and I want to see this stats on the screen in lock mode).
Does anyone knows how to do this without installing additional software on the PC. It would be better if it could be done that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an included feature of Windows, you'll need to use third party software and I would advise against it.

Something like [this](http://www.hacksar.com/blog/2009/03/23/how-to-lock-your-computer-and-still-see-desktop-autohotkey/) is probably your best option but Windows does not have this feature.